# Button located in ListView row always fired in the last row

Tags: java, android, listview, custom-adapter

I have a listview (not recyclerView) in which each row has a buttons, couple of textviews and an EditText.
Once I click on the specific button("editTremp") I want the EditText to go into edit mode.

**My problem is:** every time I press the button (no matter in which row) it fired only on the last row in the listview, and not in the specific row where the button is located. I've seen a lot of answers but no one works for me.
How can I fix it?

This is the layout for listview_row

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/listrow_drawable"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"  >
    
        <EditText
            android:enabled="false"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            style="@android:style/Widget.TextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/user_msg"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/user_image"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_date_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_phone"
            android:autoLink="phone"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_msg"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_name" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_extra"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="90dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_msg" />
    
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_remove"
            android:id="@+id/remove"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_extra"/>
    
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_edit"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/remove"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_extra"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/phone_btn"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_phone"
            android:onClick="makePhoneCall"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_extra"/>
    
        <ImageButton
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_submittext"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/edit"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_extra"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/submitText"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_uid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/user_date_time"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/user_msg"
            android:text="hello"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/user_photo_drawable"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_car"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

this is my custom adapter and the button click for "editTremp" located here

```
 public class personalZoneAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TrempData>  {

    private TextView  msg , extra,phone ,date_time ,uid ;
    private EditText name ;
    private ImageButton deleteTremp , editTremp , phoneBtn , submitText ;
    private ImageView sideview;
    private int layoutResource;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    public personalZoneAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, ArrayList<TrempData> list) {
        super(context, layoutResource, list);
        this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            final LayoutInflater Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = Inflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);
        }

        final TrempData data = getItem(position);

        //data.setPos(position);
        //int[] androidColors = getContext().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidcolors);
        //int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];

        if (data != null) {
            name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_phone);
            date_time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_date_time);
            msg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_msg);
            extra = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_extra);
            uid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_uid);
            deleteTremp = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            editTremp = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.edit);
            phoneBtn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.phone_btn);
            submitText = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.submitText);
            sideview = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.user_image);

            if (name != null & phone != null & msg != null & date_time != null & uid != null) {
                name.setText(data.get_name());
                //name.setTextColor(randomAndroidColor);
                phone.setText(data.get_phone());
                date_time.setText(data.get_timestamp());
                msg.setText(data.get_from() + "--> " + data.get_to() + ", " + data.get_date() + ", " + data.get_time());
                uid.setText(data.get_uid());

                editTremp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        submitText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        name.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(WHITE));
                        name.setEnabled(true);
                        name.setCursorVisible(true);
                        name.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        name.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                        name.requestFocus();

                    }
                });

                submitText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mDatabase.child("Posts").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    TrempData tremp = getItem(position);
                                    if (ds.getKey().toString().equals(tremp.get_key())) {
                                        name.setEnabled(false);
                                        String new_name = name.getText().toString();
                                        name.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(TRANSPARENT));
                                        submitText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        data.set_name(new_name);
                                        mDatabase.child(ds.getKey().toString()).child("_name").setValue(new_name);
                                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"הטרמפ עודכן בהצלחה" + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });


                phoneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + data.get_phone()));
                        getContext().startActivity(i);
                    }
                });




                deleteTremp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    TrempData tremp = getItem(position);
                                    if (ds.getKey().toString().equals(tremp.get_key())) {
                                        mDatabase.child(ds.getKey().toString()).removeValue();
                                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"הטרמפ נמחק בהצלחה",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"ישנה בעיה. אנא נסה שוב",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });


                if(data.get_extras().length() == 0) extra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                extra.setText("הערות:" + " " + data.get_extras());

                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(uid.getText())){
                    deleteTremp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    editTremp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    phoneBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    sideview.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(255,164,30));
                }
                else{

                    submitText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    deleteTremp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    editTremp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    phoneBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    sideview.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(176,176,176));
                }
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

and this is the activity

```
    public class PersonalZone extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView personalzone_lv;
    private personalZoneAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<TrempData> personaldataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FloatingActionButton logoutbtn , addbtn , userprofileBtn;


    public PersonalZone(){}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_personal_zone);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        logoutbtn = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.logout);
        addbtn = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingAdd);
        userprofileBtn = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.profile);
        personalzone_lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myzone_listview);
        adapter = new personalZoneAdapter(this,R.layout.personal_zone_listview_row,personaldataArrayList);
        personalzone_lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        updateMyZone();
        personalzone_lv.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptylist));

        logoutbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAuth.signOut();
            }
        });

        addbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                Addtremp trempDialog = new Addtremp();
                trempDialog.show(manager, "Addtremp");
            }
        });

        userprofileBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(PersonalZone.this, UserProfile.class));
            }
        });

    }

    public void updateMyZone(){

        mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                personaldataArrayList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    TrempData trempData2 = ds.getValue(TrempData.class);
                    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().toString().equals((ds.getValue(TrempData.class).get_uid()))) {
                        personaldataArrayList.add(0, trempData2);
                        personalzone_lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                personaldataArrayList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    TrempData trempData2 = ds.getValue(TrempData.class);
                    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().toString().equals((ds.getValue(TrempData.class).get_uid()))) {
                        personaldataArrayList.add(0, trempData2);
                        personalzone_lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    /*@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        this.finish();
        overridePendingTransition  (R.anim.slide_out, R.anim.slide_out);
    }*/
}
```

**UPDATE:**
the solution with **ViewHolder works great**!
this is the new adapter code with the ViewHolder. If you have any suggestion for improvement it will be great!

```
    public class personalZoneAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TrempData>  {

    static class ViewHolderItem{
        private TextView  msg , extra,phone ,date_time ,uid ;
        private EditText name ;
        private ImageButton deleteTremp , editTremp , phoneBtn , submitText ;
        private ImageView sideview;
    }


    private int layoutResource;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    public personalZoneAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, ArrayList<TrempData> list) {
        super(context, layoutResource, list);
        this.layoutResource = layoutResource;
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

        if (view == null) {
            final LayoutInflater Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = Inflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            viewHolder.phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_phone);
            viewHolder.date_time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_date_time);
            viewHolder.msg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_msg);
            viewHolder.extra = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_extra);
            viewHolder.uid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_uid);
            viewHolder.deleteTremp = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            viewHolder.editTremp = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.edit);
            viewHolder.phoneBtn = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.phone_btn);
            viewHolder.submitText = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.submitText);
            viewHolder.sideview = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.user_image);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final TrempData data = getItem(position);

        //data.setPos(position);
        //int[] androidColors = getContext().getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidcolors);
        //int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];

        if (data != null) {

            if (viewHolder.name != null & viewHolder.phone != null & viewHolder.msg != null & viewHolder.date_time != null & viewHolder.uid != null) {
                viewHolder.name.setText(data.get_name());
                viewHolder.name.setTag(data._name);
                //name.setTextColor(randomAndroidColor);
                viewHolder.phone.setText(data.get_phone());
                viewHolder.name.setTag(data._phone);
                viewHolder.date_time.setText(data.get_timestamp());
                viewHolder.name.setTag(data._timestamp);
                viewHolder.msg.setText(data.get_from() + "--> " + data.get_to() + ", " + data.get_date() + ", " + data.get_time());
                viewHolder.uid.setText(data.get_uid());
                viewHolder.name.setTag(data._uid);

                viewHolder.editTremp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        viewHolder.submitText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        viewHolder.name.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(WHITE));
                        viewHolder.name.setEnabled(true);
                        viewHolder.name.setCursorVisible(true);
                        viewHolder.name.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        viewHolder.name.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                        viewHolder.name.requestFocus();

                    }
                });

                viewHolder.submitText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    TrempData tremp = getItem(position);
                                    if (ds.getKey().toString().equals(tremp.get_key())) {
                                        viewHolder.name.setEnabled(false);
                                        String new_name = viewHolder.name.getText().toString();
                                        viewHolder.name.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(TRANSPARENT));
                                        viewHolder.submitText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        data.set_name(new_name);
                                        mDatabase.child(ds.getKey().toString()).child("_name").setValue(new_name);
                                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"הטרמפ עודכן בהצלחה" + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });


                viewHolder.phoneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + data.get_phone()));
                        getContext().startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.deleteTremp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    TrempData tremp = getItem(position);
                                    if (ds.getKey().toString().equals(tremp.get_key())) {
                                        mDatabase.child(ds.getKey().toString()).removeValue();
                                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"הטרמפ נמחק בהצלחה",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"ישנה בעיה. אנא נסה שוב",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });


                if(data.get_extras().length() == 0) viewHolder.extra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.extra.setText("הערות:" + " " + data.get_extras());

                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(viewHolder.uid.getText())){
                    viewHolder.deleteTremp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.editTremp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.phoneBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewHolder.sideview.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(255,164,30));
                }
                else{

                    viewHolder.submitText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewHolder.deleteTremp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewHolder.editTremp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewHolder.phoneBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder. sideview.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(176,176,176));
                }
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: use ViewHolder pattern in`Adapter`.

Comment: can you give me more details plz? how do i do that?

Comment: look at this [example](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

Comment: so in the ViewHolderItem i need to declare all of my views wich i have in the row layout?

Comment: Create a Viewholder class in your adapter and then in getView method view.setTag(your view holder object), so that you can get click event for particular position

Answer (score 0):

you can use Recycleview and set custom adapter:

Adapter:

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {


Context ctx;
public ArrayList<String> mListItem;
ArrayList<String> item;

public TestAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<String> mListItem) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.mListItem = mListItem;


}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.row_watch_company, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ViewHolder mViewHolder = (ViewHolder)holder;
    mViewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do your task
        }
    });

}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 10;
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Button button;

    public ViewHolder(View rowView) {
        super(rowView);
        button = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

}
```

}

Recyclerview in fragment / activity:

```
rvAdvisor = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvAdvisor);
rvAdvisor.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
rvAdvisor.setAdapter(new TestAdapter (getActivity());//pass data here
```